# Android get Textview text on the same row of listview

Tags: java, android

I have this code inside my BaseAdapter Adapter:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View vi=convertView;

   if(convertView==null) 
       vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_friends_layout, null);

   TextView friendsName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvFacebookName); // Friends thumb
   friend_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ivFacebookPicture);  // thumb image

   song= new HashMap<String, String>();
   song = data.get(position);
   friendsName.setText(song.get(MyFriends.KEY_FBNAME));
   //Log.i("Facebook Pangalan", ""+MyFriends.KEY_FBNAME);

   FriendName = (String) friendsName.getText().toString();

   FBID = song.get(MyFriends.KEY_FBID); 
   String fbAvatarUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+ FBID +"/picture";
   //Log.i("FBID", FBID);
   BitmapManager.INSTANCE.loadBitmap(fbAvatarUrl, friend_image, 100,100);
   Button btn=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
   if (FBID.equals(""))
   {
       btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   else 
   {
       btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
   }
   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 

       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           LOCK_BASEDATA = MyFriends.LOCK_BASEDATA;
           if (LOCK_BASEDATA.equals("0")) 
           {
               //FACEBOOK FRIENDS
               Log.i("", ""+FriendName);
               //AddfromFacebookFriends();
           }
           else if (LOCK_BASEDATA.equals("1"))
           {
               //MY REQUEST
               //((MyFriends)context).SetMyRequest();
               //Log.i("LangYa", "Langya");
           }
           else if (LOCK_BASEDATA.equals("2"))
           {
               //FRIEND REQUEST
               //((MyFriends)context).SetFriendRequest();
               //d2papasok
               AddFriendRequest();
           }

       }

    });

   return vi;
}
```

I am logging my friend's name whenever I click on the button. Now my problem starts when I click the button; I am not getting my desired string. It is getting the string from another row of my listview.

**EDIT**
Thanks, actually ive just aaded this code

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LOCK_BASEDATA = MyFriends.LOCK_BASEDATA;
                if (LOCK_BASEDATA.equals("0")) 
                {
                    //Object x =btn.getTag();
                    //String sa = x.toString();
                    View parentView = (View) arg0.getParent();
                    String textviewtext = ((TextView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.hiddentv)).getText().toString();
                    //FACEBOOK FRIENDS

                    AddfromFacebookFriends(textviewtext);

                }
                else if (LOCK_BASEDATA.equals("1"))
                {
```

I am just getting my parents View to get my desired textview and now it works. Thanks anyway

Comment: What is the `desired string` (your `friendsname`)?

Comment: @Killrawr it must be based on the same row. I am getting string on another row of my listview

Comment: You should be adding header or footer view or something of this sort. Please try to click the Last and First items. Do you get an exception?

Comment: Try using an [onItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Comment: @SherifelKhatib I am not getting exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the FriendName using this code:

```
TextView friendsName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tvFacebookName);
FriendName = (String) friendsName.getText().toString();
```

This is not The FriendName of the ListView item you clicked. Its the FriendName of the newly created ListView item. Because in getView(), the ListView item you get is the newly created one.

**One way to solve this is:**

Use tags like KunalK suggested. I am not sure if it works...i never tried it.

**Or the other way is:**

onButtonClicked get the `Position` of the ListView item you clicked, and get the respective `Name` from the ArrayList you are using.

Here the `Position` is not the `position parameter` in  the getView(). That gives the position of the newly created ListView item again.

Use this to get the actual position of the clicked item:

```
int clickedItemPosition = yourListView.getPositionForView((View) yourButton.getParent());
```

Answer (score 1):

you should go with this by setting the "FriendName" in your button's setTag property. and whenever you handle your button click event fetch your FriendName String by using getTag property of button. for e.g. something like this:

```
....
btn.setTag(FriendName);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       LOCK_BASEDATA = MyFriends.LOCK_BASEDATA;
       if (LOCK_BASEDATA.equals("0")) 
       {
           //FACEBOOK FRIENDS
           Log.i("", ""+btn.getTag().toString());
           //AddfromFacebookFriends();
       }
       else if (LOCK_BASEDATA.equals("1"))
       {
           //MY REQUEST
           //((MyFriends)context).SetMyRequest();
           //Log.i("LangYa", "Langya");
       }
       else if (LOCK_BASEDATA.equals("2"))
       {
           //FRIEND REQUEST
           //((MyFriends)context).SetFriendRequest();
           //d2papasok
           AddFriendRequest();
       }

   }

});
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the name from the list can be accompished by using an onListItemClick method as follows (*not* in your adapter, but in the class with your list):

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    TextView friendsName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvFacebookName);   
    FriendName = (String) friendsName.getText().toString();    
}
```

Since this code is the `onListItemClick` method, the `View v` parameter is the view of the row you clicked.  Once you have that, you search that particular row view for the TextView you want and then pull the string from that.

You had the right idea, you just put it in the wrong place.